# Unit test code coverage issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I am trying to find out why my unit test for the below given code is not showing full code coverage in vs2010 .
Here is my method I am using to get records .

```
public Records GetTestRecords(HttpWebRequest request)
{
    var Records = new Records();

    try
    {
        if (null != request)
        {
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                jsonResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            Records = myHelper.Deserialize<Records>(jsonResult);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {

        throw (exception);
    }

    return Records;
}
```

Here is my unit test for the above method

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void GetRecordsTest()
    {
        string mockjsonResult = "{\"recordId\":\"8cccf2deb-4dde-450c-97cd-a6ec\",\"billingAccountId\":\"fake\",\"userid\":81233,\"Checkid\":2533004436741,\"partName\":\"redcredetest\",\"Description\":\"not yet pulling- test\",\"productId\":\"rr43556-23re\",\"created\":\"2013-04-12T21:09:54.4890986Z\",\"enddate\":null,\"autoRenewal\":true,\"changeLog\":{\"reason\":\"dummy.\",\"state\":1,\"time\":\"2013-04-12T21:09:54.48126Z\",\"extensions\":null,\"transactionId\":null}}";


        var mocrequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://social.stackoverflowtest.com/Forums/getfile/2234");
        myProvider target = new myProvider (); 
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)mocrequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json"; 
        Records records = GetMockRecords();
        string jsonResult = string.Empty;

        var mockWebResponse = request.GetResponse();
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            jsonResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        records = MyHelper.Deserialize<Records>(mockdjsonResult);
        Assert.IsNotNull(records.ProductId);
    }
```

I am not able to get full code coverage with this unit test .What I am doing wrong with my unit test here.

Comment: Probably because the unit test is not causing an exception...

Comment: How do you know it's not 100%?  The Visual Studio profiler should show which lines are and are not being executed.

Comment: What is the purpose of catching the exception if you're just going to throw it anyway without any additional logic?

Answer (score 2):

Well you are not testing the catch path of your method.

Write another unittest which throws the exception.

I would use the `ExpectedException` Attribute:

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(Exception), "No exception was thrown.")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Base one your code, to make sure code coverage increase, you still lack more cases at here:

1. Unit test to test case for  `request == null`
2. Unit test to make sure the exception throw correctly.

Hope this help.